# gradle no build output on windows

Tags: windows, gradle, build

when executing gradle build for the minimal project of

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-gradle.git
cd gs-gradle
cd complete
gradle build
```

no build output folder containing the temporary files / final jars is created on windows.

On a linux host everything works as expected.
Where can I find the produced artifacts?

Comment: What about logs? Did you try with `-i` ?

Comment: @ToYonos please see https://gist.github.com/georgThesis/d5289c39994d1a4e7ec0762fd3b7b923

Comment: Everything seems to be written in `C:\tmp\complete\complete` but i don't know why...